# NSNotificationCentre for application:openURL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to call a method in my main view controller when my app receives an open from a URL Scheme so i can handle it.

The problem is i cannot seem to call ViewController methods from the app delegate. I did notice some delegate methods allow for `NSNotificationCentre` to be notified but it doesn't seem like openURL is one of those.

Is there any other method i can use for calling a ViewController method from the delegate either with a notification or just standard method call?

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call directly. Well I explain: I suppose than you are using storyboard, and you don`t have any reference of your viewController in you AppDelegate.

Now, you have said than you can fire a methods in your MainViewController, well probably your MainViewController is inside an UINavigationController (or not), I'm going to call this mainController in this example as: MainViewController.

Well first thing in your MainViewController.h (interface) make the method you want to call public, example.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

-(void)wakeUpFromUrlWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

Now In your AppDelegate.m, import your mainViewController,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
```

You can see your appDelegate has a property call window. Well, in any methods of you appDelgate you can use this window property.

If your mainViewController is inside an UINavigationController, you need to do:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController *)[navController.viewControllers firstObject];

// And you can call you methods also with a dict of parameters o any other thing

[mainViewController wakeUpFromUrlWithParameters:nil];
```

If your mainViewController is root (without Navigation Controller is easy)

```
 MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 // And you can call you methods also with a dict of parameters o any other thing

 [mainViewController wakeUpFromUrlWithParameters:nil];
```

Of course NotificationCenter is other option. (You have userInfo).

Comment: Sweet. Is there a reason the ViewController.h file has to go in AppDelegate.m? (Just so i know)

Comment: Yes, In the example in the App Delegate you are creating a pointer to ViewController, and fire a method of it. Your AppDelegate need to know this object in other to do this things.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation. Works a treat